# A couple of questions about the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

For simplicity, I'll work with a function of two variables. If one wanted to get the directional derivative with respect to $x$ at $(a,b)$, the following equation just makes complete sense to me

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)}{h}$$

Yet, there seems to be a way to write the same equation with vectors, if I understood correctly, it would be like this:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(v+hu)-f(v)}{h}$$

Where $v$ & $u$ are vectors, specifically, $u$ is the unit vector in the direction of $x$ and $v =         \begin{bmatrix}
        a\\
        b\
        \end{bmatrix}$

I suppose the equation can be written as this because putting a vector as an input into a function is equivalent as putting in the point to which the vector goes. In the sense that $f(a_1,a_2, ... , a_n) = f(v), v = \begin{bmatrix}
        a_1\\
        a_2\\
\vdots \\
a_n
        \end{bmatrix}$

### Is this right?

The big issue that I have is that of $hu$. Let's say that the directional derivative with respect to $x$ at $(a,b)$ equals $D$, then I understand that substituting $u$ by $mu$ into the equation would yield $mD$, what I do not understand is

### why is it that the vector $u$ has to have a magnitude of $1$ in order for the equation to yield the derivative?

---

Any helps/thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: In the first expression, you implicitly also used a unit vector: $u=[1 0]$. So, you could also ask: why not use $f(a+mh,b)$ for some real number $m\neq 0$ in your very first equation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are intentionally identifying vectors with tuples.  No harm there.

To answer your bold question, it doesn't have to be.  There is nothing mathematically wrong with defining $D_{\mathbf{u}}(f)(a,b)$ for non-unit (but still non-zero) vectors $\mathbf{u}$.  However...

This vector $\mathbf{u}$ is gauging the **rate of change** in the direction of a line.   Would you rather speak of your car's speed in kilometers per 6.2 hours or in terms of kilometers per hour?  (Neither is technically "wrong.")  For this reason, we typically use unit vectors in the directional derivative.